# How to not update a field on postUpdate?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity Listener and if a user changes the record, an updatedAt field is set to the current time.

Yet now the requirements have changed and I need to run a script and update all the entities at once but it should not mess with the user-generated updatedAt-field.

So I want to build a command that updates all entities, yet the updatedAt-field should not be updated.

I am wondering how I could pass through such a parameter.

At the moment I am wondering if I should add a doUpdateUpdatedAt-field on the entity, and for the command set it to false. Yet I wonder if there is a different way. I think the asset should not be concerned if the updatedAt-field is set, I think it should happen when I persist the entity or on flush.

I like to have some feedback on what possibilities there are and what their pros and cons are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener is registered as a service which means one can access it within a command quite easily over the container and set the required properties:

```
class UpdateAssetCategoryCountCommand extends AbstractCommand
{
    ...

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $assets = $this->findAllAssets();
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $listener = $this->getContainer()->get('my.listener');
        $listener->doNotUpdateTimeStamp();

        foreach ($assets as $asset) {
            // change the required fields
            $em->persist($asset);
        }

        $em->flush();
    }
```

And in my listener:

```
class MyListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $shouldUpdateTimestamp = true;

    ...

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $arg)
    {
        $entity = $arg->getObject();
        $em = $arg->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof Asset) {
            $entity->updateCategoryCount();
            $entity->preUploadHandlerIfFileUploaded();

            if ($this->shouldUpdateTimestamp) {
                $entity->setUpdatedAt(new DateTime('now'));
            }

            $this->persistChanges($em, $entity);
        }

    public function doNotUpdateTimeStamp()
    {
        $this->shouldUpdateTimestamp = false;
    }


}
```